# Windows and .NET's ProtectedData equivalent on Android?

Tags: android, encryption, android-security

I want to save some sensitive data (for example, Windows network ID/password) encrypted on an Android device. I am not trying to protect the data from the user; I am trying to protect the data on behalf of the user. I want the data remain encrypted as long as the user has not logged in, so that if a bad person gets access to the physical storage and try to read the data bypassing the OS's authentication.

On Windows and .NET, one can use "[System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx)". The data is encrypted by the Windows account so it does not require an encryption key. If the encrypted data is stored on the disk, you cannot decrypt encrypted the data, even if you bypass the OS by attaching the disk to another computer or booting into another OS.

I have searched Google and Stack Overflow, and most answers directed Account Manager. But I think Account Manager is not good for my case, because I do not want this data to appear in the Settings > Accounts, or used by any other apps. I can encrypt the data using my own code and encryption key, but then the data can be decrypted on another system running my app (I can prevent this but it would need extra ideas and work and be vulnerable to reverse engineering).

What could be the best choice in this case? If there is no such convenient thing like ProtectedData on Android, is there any unique key that I can use for encryption? It must be unique to that account on the device, and not guessable.

Comment: Have you seen: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SecurityFeatures

Comment: Thank you. That document seems long, but may contain what I need. I will read it.